# Display one div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on a link on the menu, a div slides down to show some contents. But the problem is, I only want one div at a time.

As you can see on the fiddle, if you click on one link, a div appears, if you click on another link, another div appears below the the first div.

I only want one DIV at a time. What should I modify in my javascript code to do that?

PS: I want my div to hide if I click on the same link again :

Click "HOME" -> Show div
Click "HOME" -> close div

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
  });
   $("#flip2").click(function(){
    $("#panel2").slideToggle("fast");
  });
     $("#flip3").click(function(){
    $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
  });
     $("#flip4").click(function(){
    $("#panel4").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/8/

Thanks for your answers guys, I really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok buddy, first of all, you can't have more than 1 element with the same id, so that should be the first thing you clear, second of all you can clean your markup a bit and have something easier to manage for example:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a class="flip" href="#panel1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="flip" href="#panel2">Agenda</a></li>
      <li><a class="flip" href="#panel3">Media</a></li>
      <li><a class="flip" href="#panel4">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
...
<div class="panel" id="panel1">
    <div>Anatomy</div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel2">
    <div>Anatomy is</div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel3">
    <div>Anatomy is destiny.</div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel4">
    <div>Anatomy is destiny555.</div>
</div>
```

Now you can target all the links and panels simply by their class (should clean up your css as well).

Then comes the javascript:

```
$(".flip").on("click", function(e) {        
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(target).slideToggle("fast");
    $(".panel").not(target).hide();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/43/

Comment: +1 I was going to post basically the same answer, the only issue is that you should not hide the target when doing `$(".panel").hide();` or else it will not toggle correctly

Comment: @koala_dev, thanks for the +1 :) Not entirely sure what you mean about the toggle ? Check the fiddle, it seems to be working, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Click on one link, the content opens, then click again, content should close

Comment: @koala_dev Ah I see what you mean, not sure it needs to close, but let me modify the answer.

Comment: Yes that's it :) OP has now updated the question with that requirement (he posted it before in a comment below)

Comment: Can I remove "e.preventDefault();" ? Because I added this line "$("#video").slideToggle("fast");" to hide the video when there's a DIV shown and it was buggy but it worked after removing preventDefault.

EDIT: nevermind, it's still buggy when I remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same HTML and have something more simple using this approach:

Mainly I traverse all your links inside the UL, and could use only a function the binding the click.

before making the panel link visible, must hide all the others that are visible

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav ul a").click(function(){
    $('#layer > div:visible').hide();
    $('#' + (this.id).replace('flip','panel')).slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/29/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('.current').hide();
        $("#panel").addClass("current").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $("#flip2").click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('.current').hide();
        $("#panel2").addClass("current").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $("#flip3").click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('.current').hide();
        $("#panel3").addClass("current").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $("#flip4").click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('.current').hide();
        $("#panel4").addClass("current").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

You need to hide (or slide up -depending on the look you want) the currently displayed div.  I added a class of current to the displayed div to keep track of it.
http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/8/

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to your divs and links, and add an on click event to your links such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.linkClass').click(function(){
        $('.divClass').not($(this).parent('.divClass')).hide();
        $(this).parent('.divClass').slideToggle("fast");
    });
}
```

This will hide all the other divs except the one with the link being clicked on.

Comment: The clicked element is not the div so your slidetoggling the anchor, although the approach is good

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmXvk/)

add a class to all div instead of IDs to be faster.

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
    $(".panelClass").hide();
    $("#panel").slideDown("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to all div ..

```
 $("#flip3").click(function(){
 $(".close").hide();
 $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
```

[**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/U52rr/16/)

Comment: Thank you ! But I want my div to hide if I click on the same link again.

Click on "HOME" -> Show div
Click on "HOME" -> close div

Comment: @MarkPazovic you should update the question to include this desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var $panels = $(".panel").hide();
$(".link").click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $panel = $panels.eq($(this).data("index"));
    $panels.not($panel).slideUp();    
    if($panel.is(":visible")){
       $panel.slideUp();
        return;
    }        
    $panel.slideDown();
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/33/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

When executing the .slideToggle(), you could execute .hide() of the others at the same time.

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
$("#panel2").hide("fast");
$("#panel3").hide("fast");
$("#panel4").hide("fast");
```

This FIDDLE should help: http://jsfiddle.net/U52rr/12/